# how to convert combobox item into value and calculate it

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert selected item in combobox into a number and calculate it.

I got message like this when i try to start my vb.net program.

> Conversion from string "< 20 " to type 'Integer' is not valid

Any help is greatly appreciated.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click

    Dim LHR As Integer
    Dim TipeRetak As Integer
    Dim LbRetak As Integer
    Dim LuKer As Integer
    Dim Alur As Integer
    Dim Tambal As Integer
    Dim Kasar As Integer
    Dim amblas As Integer

    Select Case ComboLHR.SelectedIndex
        Case "< 20 "
            LHR = 0
        Case "20 - 50"
            LHR = 1
        Case "50 - 200"
            LHR = 2
        Case "200 - 500"
            LHR = 3
        Case "500 - 2000"
            LHR = 4
        Case "2000 - 5000"
            LHR = 5
        Case "5000 - 20000"
            LHR = 6
        Case "20000 - 50000"
            LHR = 7
        Case "> 50000"
            LHR = 8
    End Select

    Select Case ComboTipeRetak.SelectedIndex
        Case "Buaya"
            TipeRetak = 5
        Case "Acak"
            TipeRetak = 4
        Case "Melintang"
            TipeRetak = 3
        Case "Memanjang"
            TipeRetak = 1
        Case "Tidak Ada"
            TipeRetak = 1
    End Select

    Select Case ComboLebarRetak.SelectedIndex
        Case "> 2 mm"
            LbRetak = 3
        Case "1 - 2 mm"
            LbRetak = 2
        Case "< 1 mm"
            LbRetak = 1
        Case "Tidak Ada"
            LbRetak = 0
    End Select

    Select Case ComboLuasKerusakan.SelectedIndex
        Case "> 30%"
            LuKer = 3
        Case "10 - 30%"
            LuKer = 2
        Case "< 10%"
            LuKer = 1
        Case "0"
            LuKer = 0
    End Select

    Select Case ComboKedalamanAlur.SelectedIndex
        Case "> 20 mm"
            Alur = 7
        Case "11 - 20 mm"
            Alur = 5
        Case "6 - 10 mm"
            Alur = 3
        Case "0 - 5 mm"
            Alur = 1
        Case "Tidak Ada"
            Alur = 0
    End Select

    Select Case ComboTambal.SelectedIndex
        Case ">30 %"
            Tambal = 3
        Case "20 - 30 %"
            Tambal = 2
        Case "10 - 20%"
            Tambal = 1
        Case "< 10%"
            Tambal = 0
    End Select

    Select Case ComboKekasaran.SelectedIndex
        Case "Desintegration"
            Kasar = 4
        Case "Pelepasan Butir"
            Kasar = 3
        Case "Rough(Hungry)"
            Kasar = 2
        Case "Fatty"
            Kasar = 1
        Case "Close Texture"
            Kasar = 0
    End Select

    Select Case ComboAmblas.SelectedIndex
        Case "> 5/100 m"
            amblas = 4
        Case "2 - 5/100 m"
            amblas = 2
        Case "0 - 2/100 m"
            amblas = 1
        Case "Tidak Ada"
            amblas = 0
    End Select

    Dim comand As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `tb_bnkt`(`nomor`, `Nama`, `kondisi prioritas`) VALUES (@nomor,@NamaRuas,@kondisi)", Connector)
    comand.Parameters.Add("@nomor", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextNomor.Text
    comand.Parameters.Add("@NamaRuas", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboNamaRuas.Text
    comand.Parameters.Add("@kondisi", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 17 - (Val(LHR + TipeRetak + LbRetak + LuKer + Alur + Tambal + Kasar + amblas))

    If comand.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Data disimpan")
        Loading()
        TextNomor.Clear()
        ComboNamaRuas.Text = String.Empty
        ComboLHR.Text = String.Empty
        ComboTipeRetak.Text = String.Empty
        ComboLebarRetak.Text = String.Empty
        ComboLuasKerusakan.Text = String.Empty
        ComboKedalamanAlur.Text = String.Empty
        ComboTambal.Text = String.Empty
        ComboKekasaran.Text = String.Empty
        ComboAmblas.Text = String.Empty
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The `SelectedIndex` is the index of the item selected, which is obviously not what you're checking there.  If you want to check the text then use the `Text` and if you use the SelectedIndex` then check the index.  That said, in the first case at least, you don't need a `Select Case` because you can simply assign the `SelectedIndex` directly to `LHR`.

Comment: Also make use of the text property of the combo box instead of it's selected index

Comment: thank you @jmcilhinney , i changed SelectedIndex into Selecteditem and it works.

Answer (score 0):

With simple class and data-binding you can simplify your code a little bid and get rid of current problem as well.

```
Public Class MyItem
    Public ReadOnly Name As String
    Public ReadOnly Value As Integer

    Public Sub New(name As String, value As Integer)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub
End Class

' Then in constructor create collection of values and bind it ot the combobox

Dim LHRValues As New List(Of MyItem) From
{
    New MyItem("< 20 ", 0),
    New MyItem("20 - 50", 1),
    New MyItem("50 - 200", 2),
    New MyItem("200 - 500", 3),
    New MyItem("500 - 2000", 4),
    New MyItem("2000 - 5000", 5),
    New MyItem("5000 - 20000", 6),
    New MyItem("20000 - 50000", 7),
    New MyItem("> 50000", 8)
}

ComboLHR.DisplayMember = "Name" ' Property Name will be used as a text
ComboLHR.ValueMember = "Value" ' Property Value will be used as a value
ComboLHR.DataSource = LHRValues

' Then in the code where you need selected value

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    Dim selectedLHR As Integer = DirectCast(ComboLHR.SelectedValue, Integer)
    ' Other selected values
End Sub
```

You only need to cast `ComboLHR.SelectedValue` to the type you expect (`Integer`), because `SelectedValue` is of type `object`. I hope you have `Option Strict` set `On`.